# Determine location of jar file from import

Tags: eclipse

If I have an import statement like:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
```

is it possible to determine in Eclipse the jar file where this class is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ctrl-shift-t
type BitmapDescriptor
then show in Package Explorer
```

Comment: ctrl-alt-t doesn't do anything. What menu items should I select?

Comment: sorry typo, ctrl-shift-t aka navigate-Open Type